# How to fetch result set containing only numeric value from varchar column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in following format. Volume of data is above 100k.
I have id column which is varchar(8). It can contain digits 0 to 9 and characters a to z(Small characters).

```
ID          Name
-------------------   
123         Abhinav
a12b        Rajesh
2bj5K       Manish
344         Utkarsh
```

I need to fetch only those ids which has numbers only.

I want result set AS

```
ID         Name
----------------
123        Abhinav
344        Utkarsh
```

I have query. I want to know if this query will provide me best solution:

```
SELECT
    ID, Name
FROM  
    Emp
WHERE
    ID = UPPER(ID)
```

Comment: No; the comparison between two UPPER() calls on the same value will always be equal.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i have modified query.

Comment: A12B is the same in the original and in the upper-case form.  I suggest not bending your query further; use the answer you've been given.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `ISNUMERIC` ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)):

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM Emp WHERE ISNUMERIC(ID)=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use regex:

```
Select ID,Name
FROM Emp
Where ID not like '%[A-Z]%'
```

Comment: is it OK to use Like operator if we are querying large data.In my case data will more than 100K rows

Comment: @AbhinavSingh 100K is considered a quite small table. It should be OK, but test on real dara to find out

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to get only those ID with numbers would be to use [`like`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) comparisons:

```
select ID, Name
from Emp
where ID not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

This code will correctly filter out records with ID like `34-6` or `1.33`, which will be considered as numeric by [`isnumeric()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function. So if your data will look like this:

```
ID          Name
123         Abhinav
A12B        Rajesh
2BjK        Manish
344         Utkarsh
34-6        Utkarsh
1.33        Utkarsh
```

Here's outputs you get:

```
select ID, Name
from Emp
where ID not like '%[^0-9]%'

--------------
ID         Name
123        Abhinav
344        Utkarsh
```

And for `isnumeric()` it would be

```
select ID, Name
from Emp
where isnumeric(ID)=1

--------------
ID         Name
123        Abhinav
344        Utkarsh
34-5       Utkarsh
1.33       Utkarsh
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84de9/6)</kbd>**

Comment: Of course, since the data is constrained to alphanumeric characters in the ID column, the concern about punctuation, although valid in general, is not necessary here.  Why does `isnumeric` consider `34-5` as numeric? Would it consider `123D` as numeric too?

Comment: `123D` is not numeric, but `-` and `+` signs could be considered as isnumeric. Actually I'd always prefer `like` because `isnumeric` never worked as I wanted it to work

Comment: So,if I understand correctly, `isnumeric` tests solely whether the string contains characters that could appear in a number, not whether the string is a valid representation of a number.  If so, that's a curious definition of `isnumeric`; a string of alternating plus and minus signs would be 'numeric' too.  I'll take your word for it, but it is surprising!

Comment: well, alternatins signs will not return `1` for isnumeric. But `+1` will - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/726